# Django: Query for __range

Tags: python, django

I created the following query but receive the following error `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`. The problem seems to be `created__range(start_date, end_date)`. `created` is a `timestamp` saved in the following format: **2019-12-10 21:01:58.309276+00**

```
start_date = datetime.date(2019, 10, 1)

# Filtering a DateTimeField with dates won’t include items on the last day,
# because the bounds are interpreted as “0am on the given date”.
end_date = datetime.date(2019, 11, 1)

Order.objects.filter(
    event__organizer=176,
    created__range(start_date, end_date),
    status__in=(
        OrderStatus.PAID,
        OrderStatus.REFUNDED,
        OrderStatus.PARTIALLY_REFUNDED,
    )
).count()
```

Comment: This is a syntax error, it should be `created__range=(start_date, end_date)` (with an `=`).

Comment: I missed that, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `=` operator:

```
start_date = datetime.date(2019, 10, 1)

# Filtering a DateTimeField with dates won’t include items on the last day,
# because the bounds are interpreted as “0am on the given date”.
end_date = datetime.date(2019, 11, 1)

Order.objects.filter(
    event__organizer=176,
    created__range=(start_date, end_date),
    status__in=(
        OrderStatus.PAID,
        OrderStatus.REFUNDED,
        OrderStatus.PARTIALLY_REFUNDED,
    )
).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more accurate... try with "__date__range" ... and add an "=" sign after "range"

Try with:

```
start_date = datetime.date(2019, 10, 1)

end_date = datetime.date(2019, 11, 1)


Order.objects.filter(
    event__organizer=176,
    created__date__range=(start_date, end_date),
    status__in=(
        OrderStatus.PAID,
        OrderStatus.REFUNDED,
        OrderStatus.PARTIALLY_REFUNDED,
    )
).count()
```